# Tabs with long processes in GUI all calling the same instance? [EDITED-QThread and QObject for passing objects to GUI]

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface, matplotlib

**EDIT #3:** tcaswell has solved some problems in my original problem, but now I appear to be referencing the same instance of an object when I should have several in parallel.
(see comment section of tcaswell's answer)

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM:**
I was wondering if anyone had any insight to a problem I am having with getting a user created object passed to a GUI so that the GUI will refresh itself and not move to 'Not Responding'.  I know this is fairly common issue, and I have read through several forums trying to understand QThreads, signals, slots, mutiprocessing, etc. and am still having trouble.  I am now avoiding getting a grayed out window, but now my program simply does nothing when I want it to start several large processes in the background.

My project needs to have several tabs operating in their own process, but with each tab having it's own data to show in a matplotlib plot.  I have a couple of buttons that should initiate the processing of the data and show the changes in the matplotlib plot.  A lot of the ideas of how to organize the thresds came from this thread. 
Here is the function which is initiated after the button is pressed:

```
# This appears to be where the problem lies because this should initialize all of the processes
def process_tabs(self):
    for special_object in self.special_objects_list:
        thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=self)
        worker = Worker(special_object)
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        worker.signal.connect(self.update_GUI)
        thread.start()
    return
```

The worker should be creating a whole bunch of signals in a loop that send objects to update the GUI.  Here is the worker class I have made:

```
# This class performs the iterative computation that needs to update the GUI
# the signals it send would *ideally* be special_obect objects so any of the parameters can be shown
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QObject)
    done = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, special_object):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.special_object = special_object
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def process_on_special_object(self):
        # do a long fitting process involving the properties of the special_object
        for i in range(0,99999999999999999):
            self.special_object.Y += .1
            self.signal.emit(self.special_object)
        self.done.emit()
        return
```

Thank you for any help with this, it is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have re-written the code to follow tcaswell's schema and changed the python slot decorators to pass the special_objects to the update_GUI slot.

**EDIT AGAIN:** I added a time.sleep(0.03) so the GUI will remain responsive.
Here is the new code in full form:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QtAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib import figure
import sys
import lmfit
import time
# This object will just hold certain objects which will help create data objects ato be shown in matplotlib plots
# this could be a type of species with properties that could be quantized to a location on an axis (like number of teeth)
#, which special_object would hold another quantization of that property (like length of teeth) 
class object_within_special_object:
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
    def location(self, i):
        location = i*self.m/self.n
        return location
    def NM(self):
        return str(self.n) + str(self.m)
# This is what will hold a number of species and all of their properties, 
# as well as some data to try and fit using the species and their properties
# I made this inherit QObject becuase I figured it *may* be more acceptable to send as a signal if the class inherited a PyQt4 class
class special_object(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, X, Y):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.params = lmfit.Parameters()
        self.things = self.make_a_whole_bunch_of_things()
        for thing in self.things:
            self.params.add('something' + str(thing.NM()) + 's', value = 3)
    def make_a_whole_bunch_of_things(self):
        things = []
        for n in range(0,20):
            m=1
            things.append(object_within_special_object(n,m))
        return things
# a special type of tab which holds a (or a couple of) matplotlib plots and a special_object ( which holds the data to display in those plots)
class Special_Tab(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    start_comp = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent, tmp_so):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.special_object = tmp_so
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        # matplotlib figure put into tab
        self.fig = figure.Figure()
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.plot.plot(0, 0, 'r-')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas_BBox = self.plot.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.plot.bbox)
        self.ax1 = self.plot.figure.axes[0]
        thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=self)
        self.worker = Worker(self.special_object)
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.worker.update_signal.connect(self.update_GUI)
        #        self.worker.done_signal.connect(?)
        self.start_comp.connect(self.worker.process_on_special_object)
        thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(special_object)
    def update_GUI(self, tmp_so):
        """
        have the tab update it's self
        """
        # change the GUI to reflect changes made to special_object
        self.line.set_data(tmp_so.X, tmp_so.Y)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(tmp_so.X.min(), tmp_so.X.max())
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, tmp_so.Y.max() + 0.05*tmp_so.Y.max())
        self.plot.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.plot.figure.canvas.blit(self.plot.bbox)

    def start_computation(self):
        self.start_comp.emit()

# This class performs the iterative computation that needs to update the GUI
# the signals it send would *ideally* be special_obect objects so any of the parameters can be shown
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    update_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QObject)
    done_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, tmp_so):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.tmp_so = tmp_so

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def process_on_special_object(self):
        # do a long fitting process involving the properties of the special_object
        for i in range(0,999):
            self.tmp_so.Y += .1
            time.sleep(0.03)
            self.update_signal.emit(self.tmp_so)
        self.done_signal.emit()
        return

# This window just has a button to make all of the tabs in separate processes
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    process_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # This GUI stuff shouldn't be too important
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(int(app.desktop().screenGeometry().width()*.6), int(app.desktop().screenGeometry().height()*.6))
        self.tabs_list = []
        self.special_objects_list = []
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.main_tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.main_tab_widget)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Open Tabs')
        self.layout.addWidget(button)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.open_tabs)
        button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('process Tabs')
        self.layout.addWidget(button2)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(button2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.process_tabs)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

    # Here we open several tabs and put them in different processes
    def open_tabs(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            # this is just some random data for the objects
            X = np.arange(1240.0/1350.0, 1240./200., 0.01)
            Y = np.array(np.e**.2*X + np.sin(10*X)+np.cos(4*X))
            # Here the special tab is created
            temp_special_object = special_object(str(i), X, Y)
            new_tab = Special_Tab(self.main_tab_widget, temp_special_object)
            self.main_tab_widget.addTab(new_tab, str(i))
            # this part works fine without the .start() function
            self.tabs_list.append(new_tab)
        return
    # This appears to be where the problem lies because this should initialize all of the processes
    def process_tabs(self):
        for tab in self.tabs_list:
            tab.start_computation()

        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't think you are all using the same object, and you are really having blitting issues.  At any rate, you should open a new question with the new issue.  A question thread should have a single will defined question and answer.  This makes it easier for people in the future, and will get more eyes on your problem (people who want to answer questions will not look at this one because it is marked as answered).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, I think I understand the blitting problem now which just made it appear like they were different object, but really weren't.  I just added a `restore_region` bit to the `update_GUI` function so there is only one line now.  

I'm doing well with the GUI stuff now, so Iv'e moved on to getting my fitting function to work well. Thank you very much for your help tcaswell, you're doing a great service here.

Comment: glad to be of help (maybe ignore by previous few comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you never actually call `process_on_special_object`, so the computation never gets run.

Second, I think you are not understanding signals and slots properly.  Think of them as pipes with check valves.  A `Signal` is the open end of a pipe that stuff can only flow out of and a `Slot` is on open end that stuff can only flow into.  When you connect `Signal` to `Slot` you are patching the output to the input.  When you call `emit` in a `Signal` you are pushing stuff down the pipe.  You can connect a single `Signal` to multiple `Slots` and multiple `Signals` to a single `Slot`.

Third, be careful not to shadow your class names with variable names (you seem to use `special_object` as both)

Forth, you create a zillion threads and workers, but don't do anything with them.  I would suggest a major design change.  You should think of the `Special_Tab` class as fully self contained, encapsulating the graph, the worker, and it's thread:

```
class Special_Tab(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    start_comp = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    kill_thread = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent, tmp_so):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.special_object = tmp_so
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        # matplotlib figure put into tab
        self.fig = figure.Figure()
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.plot.plot(0, 0, 'r-')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas_BBox = self.plot.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.plot.bbox)
        ax1 = self.plot.figure.axes[0]
        thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=self)
        self.worker = Worker(self.special_object)
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.worker.update_signal.connect(self.update_GUI)
        #        self.worker.done_signal.connect(?)
        self.start_comp.connect(self.worker.process_on_special_object)
        self.kill_thread.connect(thread.quit)
        thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(special_object)
    def update_GUI(self, tmp_so):
        """
        have the tab update it's self
        """
        # change the GUI to reflect changes made to special_object
        self.line.set_data(tmp_so.X, tmp_so.Y)
        self.plot.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.plot.figure.canvas.blit(self.plot.bbox)

    def start_computation(self):
        self.start_comp.emit()

    def closeEvent(self, ce):
        self.kill_thread.emit()
        QtGui.QTabWidget.closeEvent(self, ce)
```

With the related changes to `Worker`

```
# This class performs the iterative computation that needs to update the GUI
# the signals it send would *ideally* be special_obect objects so any of the parameters can be shown
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    update_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QObject)
    done_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, special_object):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.special_object = special_object

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def process_on_special_object(self):
        # do a long fitting process involving the properties of the special_object
        for i in range(0,99999999999999999):
            self.special_object.Y += .1
            self.signal.emit(self.special_object)
        self.done.emit()
        return
```

which makes your main window simpler

```
# This window just has a button to make all of the tabs in separate processes
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    process_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        ## snipped
        pass

    # Here we open several tabs and put them in different processes
    def open_tabs(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            # this is just some random data for the objects
            X = np.arange(1240.0/1350.0, 1240./200., 0.01)
            Y = np.array(np.e**.2*X + np.sin(10*X)+np.cos(4*X))
            # Here the special tab is created
            temp_special_object = special_object(str(i), X, Y)
            new_tab = Special_Tab(self.main_tab_widget, temp_special_object)
            self.main_tab_widget.addTab(new_tab, str(i))
            # this part works fine without the .start() function
            self.tabs_list.append(new_tab)
        return
    # This appears to be where the problem lies because this should initialize all of the processes
    def process_tabs(self):
        for tab in self.tabs_list:
            tab.start_computation()

        return
    # This should be the 'slot' which the signal is communicating to
    def update_GUI(self, special_object):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you tcaswell! You are a wonderful person, have all of my upvotes.  Just some quick questions, I noticed that you are using the `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` decorators.  I added a `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(special_object)` before `def update_GUI(self, tmp_so)` in my `Special_Tab` class in order for the special_object to be passed to the function as `tmp_so` in the arguments, that would be correct, right? 
After I did this, the GUI is still pretty unresponsive and the tabs are not exactly the same as they should be.  (In the real code, I will have several different user given X and Y data to fit).

Comment: @chase yes, you have the correct way to do it (fixed my post).  One thing to remember is that the updates do take time, and if you generate update signals faster than the event loop can clear them, it won't be able to process your UI events in a timely manner.  You might want to add a check to only update tabs if they are visible (no point on redrawing N-1 tabs you can't see).

Comment: Aha! I should have caught on to the need for `time.sleep()` quicker since it was the entire purpose of your post that I linked on here.  I simply added `time.sleep(0.03)` before `self.update_signal.emit(self.tmp_so)` in `def process_on_special_object(self):`  (I also updated in my question)
Still,  the process is only starting whenever I click a tab, and it appears to be using a single instance of `special_object`.  But they should all be performing in parallel with different `special_object`s, making each tab look the same (in this simplified example), at any point in time.

Comment: @chase this runs fine for me.  There is something strange going on with the `blit`, re-drawing axes.  When I try it, I get every line from when I switched to that tab.  I think there should only ever be one line per graph.  I think that is more of an mpl issue, not a qt issue, and is worthy of a new question.

Comment: @chase I also added a function to `Special_Tab` to tear down the `QThread` gracefully.